# FOSUserBundle form register inside another form

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, fosuserbundle

I would like to integrate the registration form of FOSUserBundle in another form.
This is because I have created a one to many relationship with my entity "Anagrafic."
Code here:

```
AnagraficType.php

->add('utenze', new \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType($builder))
```

But return an error.
how do I do this?

EDIT:
Ok.. doing so the problem is solved ..:

```
->add('utenze', new \My\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType('\My\UserBundle\Entity\User'))
```

But I get this error:

```
The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class \My\UserBundle\Entity\User,
but is an instance of class Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection.
You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view
transformer that transforms an instance of class
Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection to an instance of \My\UserBundle\Entity\User.
```

Why do I receive this error?
if i set "data_class" to "null" then do not take the benefits of Doctrine ..
My relationships are:

```
class Anagrafic
{
    //..
    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="My\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="anagrafic")
    */
    private $utenze;

    public function __construct()
    {
    $this->utenze = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
 *****
 class User extends BaseUser
 {
  //..
    /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="My\BusinessBundle\Entity\Anagrafic", inversedBy="utenze")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="anagrafic_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $anagrafic;
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.

```
->add('utenze', 'collection', array('type' => new \My\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType('\My\UserBundle\Entity\User')))
```

instead of

```
->add('utenze', new \My\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType('\My\UserBundle\Entity\User'))
```